# Concat Multiple Columns from Multiple Rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a table that contains the following data

```
CustomerID 3rdPartyClientID ReasonA      ReasonB   ReasonC
0001       10001            AddressCheck NameCheck Null
0001       10001            NameCheck    TakeOrder Feedback
0001       10002            TakeOrder    Null      Null
0002       10001            TakeOrder    Null      Null
0001       10002            AddressCheck NameCheck Null
```

A department is wanting the output to be a line per customer so something like:-

```
CustomerID Notes
0001       10001 - AddressCheck, NameCheck, TakeOrder, Feedback, 10002 - AddressCheck, NameCheck, TakeOrder
0002       10001 - TakeOrder
```

I'm struggling with getting the data in one 'Notes' column per customer when I have more than one 3rd Party Client ID. Any help would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use CONCAT and GROUP_CONCAT together**

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(`3rdPartyClientID`, ',', `ReasonA`, ',', `ReasonB`)
  )
FROM [table]
GROUP BY `CustomerID`;
```

**Note:**
NULL values will cause a problem. In that case CONCAT will return NULL. So fix the NULL values or make an IF ELSE statement in the QUERY.

Comment: group_concat is not available in SQL Server-2008

Answer (score 1):

You can use stuff as below

```
select CustomerId, stuff((select ','+[3rdPartyClientId]+ ' - ' +coalesce([ReasonA],'')+coalesce([ReasonB],'')+coalesce([ReasonC],'') from yourdatetable i where a.CustomerId = i.amount for xml path('')),1,1, '') 
    from yourtable a
group by CustomerId
```

If it is SQL Server 2017 or vnext you can use String_agg as below:

```
select CustomerId, string_agg([3rdPartyClientId]+ ' - ' +coalesce([ReasonA],'')+coalesce([ReasonB],'')+coalesce([ReasonC], ',')
    from yourtable a
group by CustomerId
```